# Karaf OSGI How to resolve a two dependency chain conflict for Google Guava

Tags: osgi, apache-karaf

2.8 together with its cxf feature 3.3.5, with cxf-jaxrs which is installed as feature comes a dependency to Google Guava 20.0. I have my own project where I install a couple of jars via Karaf feature, among them a Google Guava 18.0. The bundle I want now to install has a Google Guava dependency for 18.0, however i get the following error:

```
Chain 1:
  arcanite-core [arcanite-core [269](R 269.0)]
    import: (&(osgi.wiring.package=com.google.common.collect)(version>=18.0.0)(!(version>=19.0.0)))
     |
    export: osgi.wiring.package: com.google.common.collect
  com.google.guava [com.google.guava [253](R 253.0)]

Chain 2:
  arcanite-core [arcanite-core [269](R 269.0)]
    import: (&(osgi.wiring.package=com.querydsl.core)(version>=4.2.0)(!(version>=5.0.0)))
     |
    export: osgi.wiring.package=com.querydsl.core; uses:=com.google.common.collect
  com.querydsl.core [com.querydsl.core [255](R 255.0)]
    import: (&(osgi.wiring.package=com.google.common.collect)(version>=18.0.0))
     |
    export: osgi.wiring.package: com.google.common.collect
  com.google.guava [com.google.guava [172](R 172.0)] Unresolved requirements: [[arcanite-core [269](R 269.0)] osgi.wiring.package; (&(osgi.wiring.package=com.querydsl.core)(version>=4.2.0)(!(version>=5.0.0)))]
```

In my imports for the project I have explicitly imported the 18.0 version:

```
<Import-Package>
...
com.google.common.collect;version="[18.0,19.0)",
*
<Import-Package>
```

How can I get rid of this conflict, is this really about having only one version of Guava in Karaf ( OSGI ), what am i doing wrong?

Comment: I've had a similar problem with Guava conflicts. We ended up decoupling the bundles that used different Guava version using OSGi services so the bundles weren't dependent of each other. It's a nuisance with Guava.

Answer (score 0):

Ok that was a tricky one, as said the cxf-feature made up a dependecy to Guava 20.0.
Then installing my own feature with query-dsl and guvava 18.0 jar inside.
But the dependency querydsl to guava was not resolved according to maven, but according to the already existing guava in karaf so 20.0.

When i now install a bundle with query-dsl and guava 18.0 then there is the conflict.

In the end i removed 18.0 library from the feature and allowed a larger version range in my project:

...
com.google.common.collect;version="[18.0,23.0)",
*

And the conflict was gone, makes me wonder how would i specify such a dependency, here between querydsl and guava 18.0 in the feature.xml, if possible at all.